# Type having conversion to Type&& operator

Tags: c++, c++11

I was surprised to see that the following compiles:

```
struct C {
    operator C&&() {
        std::cerr << "ref'd\n";
        throw std::runtime_error("what is happening?");
    }
};
```

A type with an operator for its own rvalue-reference conversion.  However, I can't get the operator called using what I thought may do it.  Passing a value to a function taking an rvalue reference fails, and calling `std::move` on an object doesn't trigger anything.

Why is this code able to compile at all, and is there any way to actually get this function to run?

clang gives `warning: conversion function converting 'C' to itself will never be used` with or without the reference on the type.

Comment: And same result on clang for `operator C&()`.  Questions stands.

Comment: It's not technically uncallable; you can do `C c; c.operator C&&();` or take a member function pointer `C &&(C::*ptr)() = &C::operator C&&;` and use it. It will just not be used in remotely sane code.

Comment: @Wintermute The other exception is virtual dispatch.

Comment: @reymabel Oh, right. It even says so in a footnote to the section in your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
struct C
{
    operator C()
    {
    }
};
```

is also allowed and gives the same warning. It's referred to in §12.3.2/1:

> A conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly
>   cv-qualified) object to the (possibly cv-qualified) same object type
>   (or a reference to it), to a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of
>   that type (or a reference to it), or to (possibly cv-qualified) void.

In other words, it isn't forbidden, but it simply doesn't do anything. Yakk and Wintermute have already shown examples of member function call syntax, but [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator#Explanation) shows an example of virtual dispatch as alluded to in footnote 116 (N3337, footnote 118 in N4140):

```
struct D;
struct B {
    virtual operator D() = 0;
};
struct D : B
{
    operator D() override { return D(); }
};

int main()
{
    D obj;
    D obj2 = obj; // does not call D::operator D()
    B& br = obj;
    D obj3 = br; // calls D::operator D() through virtual dispatch
}
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: It's footnote 116, not 118.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think extending the lifetime of a temporary if bound to a const reference is pretty useless.

Comment: @BWG: If copy-elision was mandatory in that case... and we had had automatic type-inference from the beginning, as Stroustroup wanted... anyway, that's a serious contender.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't know what that means at all, isn't it impossible for copy-elision to not be used in such a case?

Answer (score 3):

```
void foo(C&&){}
int main(){
  C c;
  foo(c.operator C&&());
}
```

so, basically useless, but not completely.